# Update Multiple Records to a Single Record

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, sql-server-2016

I am trying to merge customer records that have the same First Name, Last Name, SSN and DOB. Below is a small sampling of our Customers table in which I identified customers that meet the merge criteria and should be merged.  Names and SSN's have been changed but the process will remain the same. By joining the Customers table to itself on FirstName, LastName, SSN, and DOB and using some `CROSS APPLY`, `DENSE_RANK`, and `LAG` magic - I was able to put each customer record in it's own row and identify which records should be merged into which account - we have decided to merge records into the largest CID.

```
CID      FirstName  LastName    SSN         DOB         MergeToCID  Ranking
5728956  RON        WILLIAMS    111111111   1988-05-17  5884361     1
5884361  RON        WILLIAMS    111111111   1988-05-17  NULL        1
1722065  JOE        SMITH       222222222   1981-01-15  2660126     2
2660126  JOE        SMITH       222222222   1981-01-15  NULL        2
3910776  MARY       JONES       333333333   1966-09-16  4019229     3
4019229  MARY       JONES       333333333   1966-09-16  4106801     3
4106801  MARY       JONES       333333333   1966-09-16  NULL        3
```

The Customer's table and columns - `FirstName`, `LastName` and `SSN` are varchar data types.

```
CID (int), FirstName, LastName, SSN, isMerged (bit), mergedTo (int), isActive (bit)
```

So if I just had Ron Williams, I could write an update like:

```
update C
set C.mergedTo = mc.MergeToCID, C.isMerged = 1, C.isActive = 0
from Customers as C
inner join #MergeCustomers as mc on mc.CID = C.CID
where mc.MergeToCID IS NOT NULL;
```

The *#MergeCustomers* would simply be a temp table of the sample data provided above.

What I have not been able to figure out how to do is update a Customer's record when we have more than 2 duplicate accounts - like the Mary Jones example.

Instead of a chain merge where we go from ID 3910776 to ID 4019229 and then ID 4019229 to ID 4106801 - both 3910776 and 4019229 should have their mergedTo column set to 4106801 but I have not been able to accomplish this.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another condition to your WHERE clause to select the maximum CID:

```
update C
set C.mergedTo = mc.MergeToCID, C.isMerged = 1, C.isActive = 0
from Customers as C
inner join #MergeCustomers as mc on mc.CID = C.CID
where mc.MergeToCID IS NOT NULL
      AND mc.MergeToCID = (SELECT MAX(mcMax.MergeToCID)
                             FROM #MergeCustomers as mcMax
                            WHERE mc.CID = mcMax.CID);
```